# get all data from a hashtag instagram with Access Token

Tags: php, instagram, social-networking, instagram-api

I want to use this call:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent

I got access token from steps :
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

But still it gives just this responce:

```
{
  pagination: {
    deprecation_warning: "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
  },
  meta: {
    code: 200
  },
  data: []
}
```

Comment: The response is telling you to use `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I know that the response is saying for min_tag_id and max_tag_id, how can we provide it.

This is what we are doing..
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/myTag/media/recent?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Result :

```
{"pagination": 
{"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []
}
```

Comment: is this an Answer ?